# Managing Multiple Fragments With ONE Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have One Activity and Three Fragments. The application launches and Fragment 1 is visible. I click on a button. The Fragment communicates with the Activity through the following Interface and launches Fragment 2:

```
public OnClickedListener listener;

static interface OnClickedListener{
    public void buttonClicked(View v);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity a;

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        a=(Activity) context;
        this.listener = (OnClickedListener)a;
    }
}
```

...

`playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });`

My MainActivity implements Fragment1.OnClickedListener, receives the data and launches Fragment 2.

Now I'm in Fragment 2. I want to click on a button and launch Fragment 3. I know that I can do that by implementing YET ANOTHER interface in Fragment 2 to then communicate to the Activity and say "Hey Launch Fragment 3". So now My Activity looks like this

`MainActivity implements Fragment1.OnClickedListener,Fragment2.OnClickedListener`

That's all fine but let's say that I have 20 Fragments. I don't want to have 20 interfaces implemented in my Main Activity. Is there a way to create and use a single interface to communicate between each individual Fragment and the Activity. How would that be implemented? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. Create only an interface (I recommend you to create it in a separate file):

```
interface OnClickedListener {
    void buttonClicked(Fragment fragment, View v);
}
```

The `onButtonClicked()` method accepts also a `Fragment` instance when a `Button` is clicked:

```
playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // You can't use just "this", pass the class instance.
        listener.buttonClicked(MyFragmentClassName.this, v);
    }
});
```

In your `Activity` you will have so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivity.OnClickedListener {
    @Override
    public void buttonClicked(Fragment fragment, View v) {
        // Check if the Fragment instance, or tag, or the info that you use to recognize it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I created a separate interface called OnClickedListener. I extended it in Fragment1 and am  able to get the the data when the button is clicked: listener.buttonClicked(MyFragmentClassName.this, v); How do i now get that to my main activity? You above wrote that my main activity should look like this: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivity.OnClickedListener. I'm not sure what youre implementing here?

Comment: As @mikhail said, declare the interface in another file or as nested in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Create one nested interface in Activity or in separate file instead of nested interfaces in Fragments.